# error when trying to create menu in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting the error :

> cannot call member function 'QMenuBar* QMainWindow::menuBar() const'
>   without object

in this function, any ideas why?

```
void TextEditor::createMenu(){
    menu = new QMenu(tr("&TextEditor"), this);
    QMainWindow::menuBar()->addMenu(menu);
    menu->addAction(tr("&Bold"), this, SLOT(setBold()), tr("Alt+B"));
    menu->addAction(tr("&Underline"), this, SLOT(setUnderline()), tr("ALT+U"));
    menu->addAction(tr("&Italics"), this, SLOT(setItalics()), tr("Alt+I"));
}
```

Comment: Is TextEditor a QMainWindow? You should only be able to call menuBar, without the qualifier. QMainWindow::menuBar() could be being treated as a call to a static method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
QMainWindow::menuBar()->addMenu(menu);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Method `menuBar()` is not a static method and you can not call it without object. You have to call it from an object:

```
main_window_object->menuBar()->addMenu(menu);
... or ...
this->menuBar()->addMenu(menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like that if your TextEditor class inherits from QMainWindow.